# Why are my node lables not displaying while using python-Louvain?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, networkx

I am trying to implement Louvain clustering algorithm and use the following code:

```
pip install python-louvain
import community.community_louvain
partition = community.community_louvain.best_partition(G)
# draw the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
# color the nodes according to their partition
cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis', max(partition.values()) + 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, partition.keys(), node_size=40,
                   cmap=cmap, node_color=list(partition.values()))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.5, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

This does output a perfect community clustered graph but, I want to be able to increase node size and print the node labels

Can anyone please help me in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nx.draw_networkx_labels](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html). In your case:

```
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for answering and it works - but it gives rise to new problems and I have posted another question - can you please look into it too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391943/how-to-resolve-the-clutter-in-my-networkx-graph-using-interactivity

Comment: My idea is to resolve the clutter and make an interactive chart with the cluster information